# What is the difference in these two loops methods?

Tags: javascript, html

So, i'm kinda new into JavaScript and i was creating a test script just to see how it works to apply style through JS, in case applying display none to the divs in the document, this is the test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 1</div>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 2</div>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 3</div>
<p><input type="button" value="hide DIV" onclick="hideDiv()"></p>
<script>
function hideDiv(){
  let test = document.querySelectorAll('div#hide')
  for(let i in test){
    test[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the onclick returns this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
at hideDiv (test.html:18)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (test.html:13)
```

And this one works well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 1</div>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 2</div>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 3</div>
<p><input type="button" value="hide DIV" onclick="hideDiv()"></p>
<script>
function hideDiv(){
  let test = document.querySelectorAll('div#hide')
  for(let i=0;i<test.length;i++){
    test[i].style.display = 'none'
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So what is the difference beetween:

```
for(let i in test){
    test[i].style.display = 'none'
}
```

And

```
for(let i=0;i<test.length;i++){
    test[i].style.display = 'none'
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea check this link.
You can find the answer.

Comment: ID must be unique !

Answer (score 3):

Just log the property being iterated over, and it'll be pretty obvious:

```js
function hideDiv() {
  let test = document.querySelectorAll('div#hide')
  for (let i in test) {
    console.log(i);
    test[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hide">Test DIV 1</div>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 2</div>
<div id="hide">Test DIV 3</div>
<p><input type="button" value="hide DIV" onclick="hideDiv()"></p>
```

`for..in` iterates over all enumerable properties on the object and on all of its internal prototypes.

A NodeList has many enumerable properties on its prototype: `.entries`, `.keys`, `.forEach`, and more. These properties are not elements, but *methods*, so when `test[i]` doesn't refer to an element, `test[i].style` will be `undefined`.

In contrast, doing

```
for(let i=0;i<test.length;i++){
```

iterates over strictly numerical values from 0 to the `length` of the NodeList, and `test[i]` will refer to an element.

Comment: Also fun: `for (const el of test)` and `test.forEach(el => ...)`, either of which is nicer than `for(let i=0; i<test.length; i++)`, unless you have Methuselah users.

Comment: Oh, Now i see, tysm man, this was bugging me, really appreciate it!